# MediaElement1 is playing, but MediaElement2 isn't. | C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, audio

I'm using MediaElements to play Local Sound Files In a WP7 Application (MP3's)

I'm using this system for Background Music (Ambience) and Button Clicks (User interaction) so there is no need for users to pause/rewind/restart this sound.

These are "play and forget" sounds, and I'd like two or three sounds to be playing simultaniously -- but right now that doesn't happen.

--

When I attempt to play My 'ButtonClick' mp3 file through the MediaElement, it works, and it can also be stopped and then restarted if the user clicks the button again.

I have it set up so when a button is clicked, the sound plays - *which it does.*

**Problems:**

*However,* my second MediaElement that is set up to play the Ambience track at the same time doesn't even play, as if it is broken, or the track cannot be found. Despite asking it to play in my code, and checking the code.

Is there any way to make two MediaElements play Simultaniously? I actually think I did it before, but I forgot how I actually achieved it.

**Current Code:**

***XAML***

```
        <MediaElement Height="120" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="89,263,0,0" 
        Name="mediaElement2" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
        Width="160" Source="Audio/ButtonClick.mp3" AutoPlay="False" />

        <MediaElement Height="120" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="89,263,0,0" 
        Name="mediaElement1" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
        Width="160" Source="Audio/OverviewMusic.mp3" AutoPlay="False" />
```

***C#***

```
        mediaElement2.Stop();
        mediaElement2.Play();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only One MediaElement can play at any given time.

Xna has functions which allow for more sounds to be playing at once, however XAML and CS don't come with this as default.